# Stop Eclipse from opening Logcat when running an Android app

Tags: android, eclipse

When doing Android development in Eclipse and running an application, my perspective stays in 'Java' but the LogCat view still opens in the sidebar (the one on the right where the Outline view is).

I don't want LogCat to open, it's annoying. If I want to look at it I can switch perspectives to DDMS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the Android > LogCat section of Eclipse's Prefereneces window and try adjusting settings in there:

[image]

In particular, the bottom two checkboxes look promising for adjusting this behavior.

Comment: The bottom one was exactly what I needed.